# Data Hub Framework and CPF

Tags: marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I am now studying about DHF.
In my understandings, harmonization process should be done inside harmonize flow.

I would like to leverage CPF for multiple binary transformation purpose, in this case what will be the best practice?
The reason am asking this Q is because, CPF hides some of the logic/process if consider from DHF perspectives.

Please let me know if am misunderstanding the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider CPF handling of binaries part of the import process, and something to happen before harmonize. I see no reason why you shouldn't use CPF together with DHF, though it makes most sense to use it in Staging, like an extension of the input flow. You use an input flow to ingest binaries, use CPF to mangle them in as many steps as you need, and then you use harmonize flows to map whatever came out of the binaries onto entities, maybe with links to original binaries that would then need to be copied to Final too.

HTH!